# Uniform continuity with Cauchy sequences

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences, uniform-continuity

Let $A\subset$ $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($A\neq \emptyset$) and $f: \mathbb{A} \to \mathbb{R}$ uniformly continuous. Prove:

$a)$ If $\left\{x_n\right\}$ is a *Cauchy* sequence of points of $A$ $\implies$ $\left\{f(x_n)\right\}$ is a *Cauchy* sequence in $\mathbb{R}$.

$b)$ $\exists !$ continuous function $g:{\overline{A}}$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$ $|$ $g(a) = f(a)$ $\forall a \in A$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Questions that don't provide any context such as motivation, source or attempt to solve are usually considered off-topic, and might be closed. This is because context helps everyone give answers appropriate for your level. So, please share with us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

**for the first**

Let $\epsilon>0$ given.

$f$ is uniformly continuous at $A$
so
$ \exists \eta>0\;:\; \forall x,y\in A $

$|x-y|<\eta\implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$

$(x_n)$ is Cauchy $\implies$

$\exists N>0\;:\; \forall p>q>N |x_p-x_q|<\eta$

$\implies \forall p>q>N \;\;|f(x_p)-f(x_q)|<\epsilon$.
qed.

**for the second**
use the fact that

$x\in\overline{A}\implies x=\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_n$ with $a_n\in A$.